# Inserting data into table using Select

Tags: sql-server, select, insert

I have a table employee1 and employee2 where I would like to insert data from one table to another using select based on a condition such as

> INSERT INTO EMPNO, EMPNAME, EMPAGE, EMPSALARY, EMPDESIGNATION SELECT
>   EMPNO, EMPNAME, 0, '', EMPDESIGNATION WHERE EMPID=25

This is what I want to achieve as there are some values which i don't want to supply because they are default or for some other reason but this is not allowed.

Can you tell me how can I achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO employee2
           (EMPNO, EMPNAME, EMPAGE, EMPSALARY, EMPDESIGNATION)
     SELECT EMPNO, EMPNAME, 0, '', EMPDESIGNATION
       FROM employee1
      WHERE EMPID=25;
```

You can specify the columns you want to provide values for, and then provide values for only those columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
insert INTO employee2 (EMPNO)
SELECT EMPNO from employee1
```